# Shipping & Payment based on Customer Groups in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, magento2.3.4, magento2.3.5

Is there a way so that we can restrict payment and shipping for various customer group in magento 2.3.5.
if anyone have tried this and can provide some guidance on how to approach this will be great.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict payment methods to specific customer groups I can recommend this module

https://github.com/galacticlabs/customer-group-payment-filters

It works with 2.3.x and I have used it in production without issues.

For shipping methods, depending on the shipping methods you use you may need to create your own plugin to achieve this.